# Max Date logic when query run for a date Range

Tags: oracle, maxdate

I am trying to run a query for a date range ,this query also has another table SECM with history on it .
So when i run the query for say 01/02/2019 ,SECM data should be retrieved from the date the query is run or any other data for which data is available from SECM but less than the date query is run for.

SECM Data

[image]

The query i am using is as below .

```
    SELECT 
SECM.EFF_DATE,
POS.EFF_DATE,
E.ACC_NO,E.ACC_NAME AS ACCOUNT_NAME,POS.ACC_ID AS ACC_ID,
SECM.CURRENCY,SECM.DESCRIPTION,
FROM
ACC E
INNER JOIN HOLDING POS ON POS.ACC_ID = E.ACC_ID
INNER JOIN POS_DETAIL POSDET ON POSDET.POS_ID = POS.POS_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT  ALIAS,DESCRIPTION,CURRENCY,EFF_DATE
                 FROM SMFH SM1 
                 WHERE INSTANCE=4 
                 AND EFF_DATE=(SELECT MAX(EFF_DATE) 
                               FROM SMFH SM2 
                               WHERE SM2.INSTANCE=4 
                               AND SM1.ALIAS=SM2.ALIAS 
                               AND EFF_DATE<='02-Jan-2019'
                              )
                ) SECM ON SECM.ALIAS = POSDET.ALIAS 
                      AND SECM.EFF_DATE <= POS.EFF_DATE
WHERE POS.INSTANCE = 14
AND TRUNC(POS.EFF_DATE) BETWEEN '30-Dec-2018' AND '02-Jan-2019'
```

When i run the above query i am always getting data for 02-Jan.
Below is the Current output.

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: Your inline view SECM is selecting EFF_DATE where `EFF_DATE=(SELECT MAX(EFF_DATE)`. So why you would expect SECM. EFF_DATE to be anything other than the maximum date which fits the other criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Number rows in `sfmh` chronologically and alias such table as `secm`. For each entry in `pos` find max row number in `secm` using correlated subquery and your criteria. Then join again with `secm` knowing max row number:

```
with secm as (
    select row_number() over(order by eff_date) rn, 
           alias, description, currency, eff_date 
      from sfmh)
select pos.eff_date, secm.eff_date, secm.description, secm.currency
  from (
    select pos.*, 
           (select max(rn) from secm 
             where alias = pos.alias and eff_date <= pos.eff_date) rn 
      from pos) pos
  left join secm using(rn)
```

Left join is needed when there is no row in `sfmh` matching `pos`.

If there is no possibility of two same dates for same alias in `sfmh` then you can simplify this solution:

```
select pos.eff_date, sfmh.*
  from (
    select pos.*, 
           (select max(eff_date) from sfmh 
             where alias = pos.alias and eff_date <= pos.eff_date) max_ed  
      from pos) pos
  left join sfmh on sfmh.alias = pos.alias and sfmh.eff_date = pos.max_ed
```

<sup>**[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d88d676e887b7add579188d9bc1c9fd0)** for both queries</sup>